# retain and keep old values of dropdownlist on submit and refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to keep Dropdownlist Selected value same after refresh or click submit page or post-back.

this is the java-script function that on change get the Dropdownlist  selected value then put it in Dropdownlist  again:

```
$("#Rooms").on('change', function (e) {
window.localStorage.setItem("Rooms", $("#Rooms option:selected").val());
$("#Rooms").val(window.localStorage.getItem("Rooms"));
});
```

this function worked when refresh the page , but not working when i click on submit button or action link on mvc i don't know why .

this is my dropdownlist inside form :

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
         {
      <select id="Rooms" name="Rooms" class="dropdown">
      @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.MaximumNumberOfRooms; i++){
         <option value="@i">@i</option>
         }
       </select>
   <input type="submit" class="btns" value=@Resource.criteria_btn_Search />
     }
```

this is my controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index_Get()
    {
        //checkURL();                        

        pageload();

        return View(mysession);            
    }
```

i tried several ways but not worked with me any advice .
thanks

Comment: You need to reload your model variables in your post action as well, for them to be injected into the view.

Comment: i can not do it with javascript or jquery

Comment: How are you doing the post to the server? by AJAX? Full Post?

Comment: Why are you not binding to a model using the `DropDownListFor()` method which handles this correctly (no scripts are required)?

Comment: @Cat_Clan Full post

Comment: @ahosam so what you want is to save the last selected value and have it set any time the user comes to the screen?

Comment: @Cat_Clan yes this is what i want

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the setup into two parts, first you need to save the value into localstorage or I would recommend using sessionStorage (to avoid long standing values saved):

```
$("#Rooms").on('change', function () {
  window.sessionStorage.setItem("Rooms", this.value);
});
```

Then you need to set back the value, but this has to be on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#Rooms").val(window.sessionStorage.getItem("Rooms"));
});
```